# How to recognise a newline within a database column

Tags: php, mysql, database, string, newline

I have the following info in a db column - how could I look for the newline so I can seperate this into an array?

```
Address1
Address2
Address3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with: "explode()"

`$arr = explode ("\n" , $the_db_column_field)`

and then into $arr you'll have te single "address1","address2","address3" etc..

(via [php official](http://php.net/explode))

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use

```
$arr = explode("\n",$string);
```

you get

```
$add1 = $arr[0];
$add2 = $arr[1];
$add3 = $arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but a warning about using non-[normalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation) data.

This is, in most cases, a horrible way to store data. You should store only one data entity per field. Consider adding another table called "addresses" where you can store multiple addresses for each row in the original table.

If you go ahead with your current solution you may see multiple problems along the way, such as: hard to search for entities with a certain address, concurrency problems if the addresses are updated from two clients at the same time and similar, impossible to store en address containing newlines and so on.

Comment: There's nothing non-normalized about having newlines stored in a database field. Although there are various national standards (and at least 2 international standards) for formatting addresses - they mostly conflict with each other - even for well defined atoms such as the postal code, its position within the address string varies by country.

Comment: symcbean, as I understood the question it's three different addresses (Address1, Address2 and Address3).